# using values from strings.xml in webview

Tags: android

My app is using webview and loads a local html file in the assets/ folder. 
Now is there a way to use all the strings from res/strings.xml in that html file webview loaded ?

Tried some and google whole night but havnt gotten to any solution, is it even possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by using? show that value in to web view? if so, just use Resource to get that string and pass as content to web view.

Comment: How do you want to use the string? Webview and android objects could talk to each other using javascript. ( demo available in android samples). Like for example, I can make a button click display an alert message, which I pass from android ( storing in string.xml).

Comment: @xandy : yes, thats what i wanna do, but i havnt found the proper way to do it or any examples on how, i manage to use the strings in the java but not shure how to pass it to the html file loaded in webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @doc_180 said, using javascript would be a great choice. This [example](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/) may serve as a good way for you to inject the string.

But of course, you may do something easier, for example, the HTML you are passing to webview is:

```
<body>
    <h1>$REPLACE_THIS</h1>
    ...
```

Then you can simply do the string replacement / regex replace before you append the html to webview for your own injection string.

E.g.

```
String html = ... // Any method to load the html file into string
html = html.replace("$REPLACE_THIS", getResouces().getString(R.string.replacement));
webview.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

---

Update

It turns out he need to dynamic refer the constant strings in R.string; Here's how it can be done:

```
public String getStringFromRes(String name){
    try{
        int resId = R.string.class.getField(name).get(null);
        return getResources().getString(resId);
    }catch(Exception e){
        // no such string
        return "empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm ill look at this, but im not shure its gonna work. Im loading webviev this way: 
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/findgps_en.html");

The local html file im loading in my app after a while redirect to yet another local html file in the assets/ folder

Comment: i might be missing something here, but it feels like those exampels are good for changing/injecting one string.... but what i wanna do is to be able to use all stings in res/strings.xml on the html pages i loaded in webview

Comment: So no-one have any ideas on how to make it possible for the html file loaded with webview to use all the strings in /res/strings.xml ?

Comment: what do you mean by using all? You can replace one string using the above mentioned method, and yet you can replace N strings using the same method.

Comment: cause it vould probably end up with 20-40 replacements it just feels there should be a smoother way to do it

Comment: Maybe you should post exactly how you wanna replace, like, how the HTML would looks like